# Unable to add content to new Plone site: ValueError: Unable to find update_version_before_edit  exception

Tags: plone

Just finished a successful install of Plone 4.2.1 on CentOs using the unified installer.  Once logged in I cannot add any content.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):

    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
    Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
    Module Products.CMFPlone.FactoryTool, line 453, in __call__
    Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
    Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
    Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 28, in _call
    Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerBase, line 231, in getNext
    Module Products.CMFFormController.Actions.TraverseTo, line 35, in __call__
ValueError: Unable to find update_version_before_edit
```

I've already run bin/buildout -n to update components.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The install above was a 'standalone' installation.  I decided to perform a 'zeo' installation and the issue does not exist.  Just a note - I was not getting drop down menus either in the standalone install, that does not exist in the zeo install either.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue today with a Plone 4.1.6. Here's a workaround:

Go to zmi -> portal_setup -> tab "import" -> select "CMFEditions" in the dropdown menu -> than hit the "import all steps" button.

The problem is that for some reason, that I couldn't find yet, the skin layer of Product.CMFEditions is not registered in the portal_skins and so when you try to create a content type that is under versioning it fails because of this. I'll investigate it more deeply but in the meanwhile this trick does its job.

Answer (score 0):

update_version_before_edit should refer to update_version_before_edit.py script.

This script

- either does not exist on your disk (failed installation)
- Zope management interface > portal_skins is misproperly configured (some kind of third party theme interference)

Can you repeat the problem with ZEO installation? If yes then it must be some kind of CentOS installer bug not setting up files properly.