# Site Cleanup after Upgrade / Migration

Tags: plone

I am going to prepare a migration from our existing Plone site hosted on a windows machine to a linux host.
Hereby i got a few problems i didnt get resolved by mysef, and I would be really glad if someone could give me a few hints about how to get my new instanze runnig in a clean manner.

Here a short summary of the steps taken during migration and upgrade to the current version.

- i did a fresh install on debian jessy with the installer (4.3.4.r1).
- to test the installation i also created a new instance and also got
  the buildout process running without errors
- copied the filestorage 
  and blobstorage of the existing instanze to the new server
- after first login i started the upgrade process form 4305->4309. this
  finished successfully, but with a few hints to non existing extensions

  - Step ploneboard-various has an invalid import handler
  - Step simpleattachment has an invalid import handler

    We tested these addons  a few years ago, and it seems they didn't get cleaned up correct.
    I tried to install a current version, so i can do a uninstall, but as they dont seem to be official supported under current plone versions i didn't succeed with this. Does anyone have a good hint how to remove such expired addons?
- In Zope Management Interface i reinstalled the addons, so that the
  correct versions get listed

  This are:

  Plone Classic Theme 1.2.5   1.3.3
  Plone JQuery Tools Integration  1.5.5   1.6.2
  Plone True Gallery  3.3.1b1 3.4.5
  Workflow Policy Support (CMFPlacefulWorkflow)   1.5.9   1.5.10
  Working Copy Support (Iterate)  2.1.10  2.1.12

As soon as i reinstall the extension Plone Classic Theme to version 1.3.3 the tinymce editor stops working (no control bar from tinymcebody and text shows up just as plain text), and i get the following errors when i try to save a new article

```
Traceback (innermost last):
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
Module Products.CMFPlone.FactoryTool, line 478, in __call__
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 28, in _call
Module Products.CMFFormController.ControllerBase, line 231, in getNext
Module Products.CMFFormController.Actions.TraverseTo, line 35, in __call__
ValueError: Unable to find update_version_before_edit.
```

When i switch the theme to "old plone classic theme" everything seems to work as before.

I solved the errors following this post:
[Unable to add content to new Plone site: ValueError: Unable to find update_version_before_edit  exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513123/unable-to-add-content-to-new-plone-site-valueerror-unable-to-find-update-versi)
But TinyMce doesn't work any more.
So, is this behavior correct, and do i have to stay with the old Plone classic theme, or is there something weird with my installation s should try correct?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

About Ploneaboard: why you say it's not supported anymore? Latest versions works properly in Plone 4.3.
However: you can manually removed those invalid import handlers by going into ZMI -> portal_setup -> "Manage" tab

About TinyMCE: this issue affects a lot of users recently. If you don't see TinyMCE editor it means you have some JavaScript errors (check your browser console log). Commonly this is fixed by manually run upgrade steps.

Go again to ZMI -> portal_setup -> "Upgrades" tab -> select "Products.TinyMCE:TinyMCE" then look for upgrade steps to be run.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you reply

I suspected it wasnt supported because compatibility under https://plone.org/products/ploneboard is just up to v4.1 an it wasn't available as a default egg via buildout.
But as you explained, i removed the import handlers throug zmi, and also deleted related entries under portal-controlpanel and Portal-types
After that it seems that the buildout and site upgrade process works without any ploneboard related errors.

About tinymce:
I did the upgrade step as suggested, but that didn't solve the problem. TinyMce Editor is only visible if i select the "Old Plone 3 Classic Theme"
I am sorry, but I didn't find useful information about this. As you said that many users were affected, can you please tell me some ressource where this problem is currently handled?

But another question to the upgrades:
I saw a few other upgrades, that i could perform:

- Products.TinyMCE:TinyMCE
- plone.app.discussion:default
- plonetheme.sunburst:default
- plone.app.dexterity:default
- plone.app.theming:default

Is it generally recommended to perform this steps manually, or shouldn't this be handled by the regular site upgrade after a version change?
For now i started the upgrade process manually, and excepts the "plone.app.theming:default" everything seems to have gone ok.
For plone.app.theming:default the upgrade step looks like this:

```
The profile "plone.app.theming:default" is currently upgraded to version unknown.
The filesystem version for the "plone.app.theming:default" profile is currently 1001.
Available upgrades:
Update registry
(all → 1000)    
Combine Theming control panels
(1000 → 1001)
```

But after upgrade i get following error when i enter  site setup - theming
ComponentLookupError: (, 'persistent')